# Merging 2 dictionaries in Python but keeping the values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This might be a possible duplicate.
I have 2 dictionaries in this format:

```
dict1={'id1':'11', 'id2':'12', 'key11':'value11', 'key12':'value12'}

dict2={'id1':'n/a', 'id2':'12', 'key21':'value21', 'key22':'value22'}
```

Notice that the only common `key` between the 2 dictionaries is `id2`. So I want my final dict to be something like this:

```
dict3={'id1':'11', 'id2':'12', 'key11':'value11', 'key12':'value12', 'key21':'value21', 'key22':'value22'}
```

Also, notice that on the `2nd` dictionary. `id1 is missing`, but on the final output, `dict3` is using the value from `dict1` because from `id2` we know it's the same dictionary.

And finally, if dict2 has no matching keys with dict1, like this:

```
dict1={'id1':'11', 'id2':'12', 'key11':'value11', 'key12':'value12'}
dict2={'id1':'n/a', 'id2':'somevalue', 'key21':'value21', 'key22':'value22'}
```

Can then dict3 be dict2 with the dict1 keys but the values set to `'n/a'`?? Like this:

```
dict3={'id1':'n/a', 'id2':'somevalue', 'key21':'value21', 'key22':'value22', 'id2':'n/a', 'key11':'n/a', 'key12':'n/a'}
```

I'm traversing 2 lists of dictionaries to do this. So my code so far is this:

```
for d1 in dlist1:
    for d2 in dlist2:
        if d1['id1']==d2['id1']:
            if d1['id2'] == 'n/a':
                d1['id2'] = d2['id2']
            d1['key21'] = d2['key21']    
            # adding the new key-value pairs to dictionary 1, one-by-one and so on ...
```

In short, I'm either adding new fields to one of the nodes in `dlist1` or adding an entirely new node to `dlist1`.
My question is: Is there a quicker pythonic way to do this? Because my implementation is giving me `KeyError's`

Comment: What you mean by *if dict2 has no matching keys with dict1*? both dictionaries have multiple common keys in your second example ?

Comment: @kasramvd they have common keys, but the values of those keys are different. So that means `dict2 doesn't match dict1`. In order for the 2 dicts to match, and merge them, it has to be that either `id1 or id2 or both` key-value pairs are the same on both dictionaries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: @BPL it's not entirely a duplicate because it doesnt handle the fields that will be left blank.